# How to retrieve Facebook link share history through api?

Tags: facebook, api, share

In my page, I have one Facebook "share" button to share the URL. Then after the URL shared and showed up in my friend's newsfeed, I don't know how many time the link got re-shared. Is there any API to read that re-share information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql) table [link_stat](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) to query for that data, something like:

```
SELECT 
    url, share_count 
FROM 
    link_stat 
WHERE 
    url="SHARED_URL"
```

Here's an example with the [official south park page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20share_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url=%22http://www.southparkstudios.com/%22).
There are more stats that you can get from that table, so be sure to read the docs.